# How do I set a property value of a struct?

Tags: swift

To set the value of `multiplier` I thought I use the syntax `threeTimesTable.multiplier = 3`. How is the below working out? It looks like I'm passing an argument to the `struct` and initializing a value, but I don't see an initializer in the class. I'm very confused by what is going on here. Is the argument optional in the `struct`?

```
struct TimesTable {
    let multiplier: Int
    subscript(index: Int) -> Int {
        return multiplier * index
    }
}
let threeTimesTable = TimesTable(multiplier: 3)
print("six times three is \(threeTimesTable[6])")
// Prints "six times three is 18"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because this is a struct, Swift provides a default memberwise initializer (classes don't have this feature). From the [Swift book](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ClassesAndStructures.html):

> **Memberwise Initializers for Structure Types**
>
> All structures have an automatically-generated memberwise initializer, which you can use to initialize the member properties of new structure instances. Initial values for the properties of the new instance can be passed to the memberwise initializer by name

In your case, this translates to:

```
struct TimesTable {
    let multiplier: Int

    // This is automatically provided by the compiler
    init(multiplier: Int) {
        self.multiplier = multiplier
    }

    subscript(index: Int) -> Int {
        return multiplier * index
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I actually found this in the book after typing up this question. But I'm sure it will be good for somebody so I'll leave it.